# Shallow or deep copy in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

If you have a list (Original) in python like:

```
class CustomID (object):                   
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ID = ''
        self.manymore = float()
        self.visited = False
        self.isnoise = False
IDlist = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
Original = list()
for IDs in IDlist:
    NewObject = CustomID()
    NewObject.ID = IDs
    Original.append(NewObject)
```

and if you do a comprehension for a new list and a function to use over the comprehension sublist:

```
def Func(InputList=list()):
    for objects in InputList:
        objects.visited = True
    return InputList
New_List = [member for member in Original if (int(member.ID)>5)]
ThirdList = Func(New_List)
```

Is this (New_List) resulting in a shallow or deep copy of the original list? The matter is relevant for me, if the original list contains objects, which attributes can change in the code to follow New_List creation (ThirdList). New_list is send to a function, which will change the attributes. The question is if you try to reuse the original list for the same function with different comprehension (lets say (members>4).

```
New_List = [member for member in Original if (int(member.ID)>4)]
```

Actually:

```
print New_List[3].visited
```

gives True.

Comment: Why don't you try (with something else than numbers in the list)? (Spoiler: It's a shallow copy. Why should it be a deep copy? You are explicitly using the original `member`s in your list comprehension.) BTW., your `New_List` is a `set`...

Comment: The slices are deep-copy-like. That would be enough, since a do not have nested lists. I am not sure if a comprehension produces a deep-copy-like output similar to slices.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, sorry, I corrected the typo. It is a list now :-)

Comment: @Ivaylo: slices are **not** deep-copy-like. They are shallow copies.

Comment: >>> list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
    >>> list2 = list1[:]
    >>> list2[1] = 'x'
    >>> print list2
    ['a', 'x', 'c', 'd']
    >>> print list1
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
To me this looks like a deep, although I admit that it is shallow.

Comment: @Ivaylo: A deep copy creates copies of the **contents** too. A shallow copy only creates a new object of the same type of the outermost object.

Comment: @Ivaylo It _looks_ like a deep copy because in both your examples you are using immutable types. Also, you are assigning new values to list elements (`list2[1] = 'x'`), not _changing_ the list elements. Try the same with, e.g., a list of lists, and `list2[1].append(stuff)`.

Comment: So, I cannot escape doing Third_List = copy.deepcopy(New_List) in the body of the function, to which I pass New_List? This is an overkill for a big sublist.

Comment: @Ivaylo: that depends entirely on what your list *contains*. If you have complex mutable objects in that list that you also need copied and not shared, then either use `copy.deepcopy()` or extend your custom objects to add a `.copy()` method that creates new objects that copy only what cannot be shared.

Comment: @tobias_k: The nested lists are another topic I know. I guess a deepcopy is my only choice or pre-cleaning with iteration over the attributes changed in a previous run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a shallow, filtered copy.

Your loop doesn't create copies of `member`, it references them directly.

Not that you would need to create copies, all objects in your original list are immutable integers. Moreover, CPython interns small integers, creating copies would only result in the *exact same objects* being used for these.

To illustrate, try to create a copy of a list containing mutable objects instead. Here I used a dictionary:

```
>>> sample = [{'foo': 'bar'}]
>>> copy = [s for s in sample]
>>> copy[0]['spam'] = 'eggs'
>>> copy.append({'another': 'dictionary'})
>>> sample
[{'foo': 'bar', 'spam': 'eggs'}]
```

The `copy` list is a new list object containing a reference to the same dictionary contained in `sample`. Altering that dictionary is reflected in both `copy` and `sample`, but appending to `copy` doesn't alter the original list.

As for your updated loop code, your sample produces a `New_List` list that still shares objects, and `New_List[3].visited` is in fact `True`:

```
>>> New_List[3].ID
'8'
>>> New_List[3].visited
True
```

because it is still the same object found in `Original` at index 7:

```
>>> New_List[3] is Original[7]
True
```

which is the same object still found in `ThirdList` at index 2:

```
>>> ThirdList[2] is New_List[3]
True
```

Comment: I admit that this is an enlightening example.

Comment: My objects are of a kind:  
`class CustomID (object):                   
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ID = ''
        self.visited = False 
 self.isnoise = False`

Comment: What could be a custom .copy() to deepcopy only self.visited lets say?

Comment: @Ivaylo: Those are simple objects with immutable attributes; adding a custom `.copy()` method to create a new `CustomID` object with those 3 attributes copied across would be fine.

Comment: I substantially rewritten my question. Please excuse my rudeness in changing my text, although the substance is the same. The output is rather paradoxical to me. If it was shallow, it should be True.

Comment: @Ivaylo: you appear to be confused as to what is being copied. You create a new *list object*, but each `member` is not being copied. In effect, you create a shallow copy of the list only.

Comment: @Ivaylo: That's what I am stating in my answer. The new list gets copies of the references, but each `CustomID` is **not** copied.

Comment: But then I change the CustomID objects in Func. How come a new comprehension is not reflecting the change?

Comment: @Ivaylo: it **is** reflecting the change. But you then create a new copy of the objects and include one that wasn't changed.

Comment: @Ivaylo: In fact, I cannot reproduce your code; I get `New_List[3].visited` returning `True`.

Comment: So my Original will not change ever in this case? Well, if I do not apply Func to Original, I assume. Lets try to repeat for my sake. I have a shallow copy in the New_List (only references). I change an object in the New_List (this should change the Original, but it does not). Then I make a new copy of Original, which has the unchanged values... Is this because Boolean is immutable?

Comment: @Ivaylo: It **does** change values in `Original`. You do need to take into account that you filtered the original list, not *all* objects are shared.

Comment: True that :-). Absolutely right. You have been very helpful as usual. I will most probably look into the solution with .copy() method in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, which worked for me is to implement a flagClear method in the class

```
class CustomID (object):                   
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ID = ''
        self.manymore = float()
        self.visited = False
        self.isnoise = False
    def flagClear(self):
        self.visited = False
        return self
```

And then, every time I construct a new list, simply to use the method:

```
New_List = [member.flagClear() for member in Original if (int(member.ID)>4)]
```

If the only thing I modify in the CustomID is the .visited flag, than this works. Obviously, it will not be perfect. If someone needs a complete solution, the suggestion of Martijn Pieters will work best (implementing .copy() method):

```
import copy
class CustomID (object):                   
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ID = ''
        self.manymore = float()
        self.visited = False
        self.isnoise = False
    def CustomCopy(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self)

New_List = [member.CustomCopy() for member in Original if (int(member.ID)>4)]
```

Thank you Martijn, this was really a learning experience for me.